# Beside ADO model generator

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am reading a tutorial of webform in which the author was using ADO EDM to generate model files from a database resource. I have created a similar database file, but my VS10 doesn't have ADOEDM installed, how can I generate a similar model without ADO-EDM ?Sorry my knowledge of ASP.NET is still limited, thank you for your help ?

I am reading this tutorial.
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/tailspin-spyworks/tailspin-spyworks-part-2

Comment: It helps if you show us the link of the article you mention...

Comment: Did you follow the steps described in Part 1 of that tutorial to create the appropriate project? http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/tailspin-spyworks/tailspin-spyworks-part-1

Comment: So, it must be some weird piece of configuration that's missing in your VS 2010 installation... this happens! :) As you said, try uninstalling and installing EF or even VS. Restart the machine, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you'll not be able to generate model classes out of your database without an ORM installed...

I think you're referring to [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) when you mention `ADO EDM`. If this is the case you can install it in VS 2010 using this NuGet package:

http://nuget.org/packages/entityframework

Comment: Thank you, I have installed the EF4.3.1 but I still can't find the ADO Entity Framework Model when I choose to add a new item to my project.

Comment: Try this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Yes, in that tutorial, the ADO-EFM appears but in my current ASP.NET webform project, it doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you clicking on the Data subcategory in the left pane?

VS 2010 has Entity Framework installed.  If it's not there, then your visual studio is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks, I guess so, but I will try to uninstall and reinstall EF to see if it works later.